# Connect to KVM remotely

Tags: server, gui, virtualization, remote-access, kvm-virtualization

If I install KVM on an Ubuntu server and create some Windows virtual machines, I will need a GUI to go through the Windows install process. Will I need to install a GUI on the server, or is there a way I can connect to KVM remotely from, say, my Windows workstation?

I know VMWare and Hyper-V allow you to connect to a virtual machine remotely, so certainly KVM does as well.... Right?

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

You should try enabling `vnc`. It works then.

## Long Answer

`QEMU` uses `SDL` for it's output (video as well as sound). You can force `QEMU` to listen to the vnc by using the `-vnc` option. 
Or you could make `vnc` the default option by adding `<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' keymap='en-us'/>` to the `/etc/libvirt/qemu/*.xml` file, in the end just after the last `</devices>` line. 
 Then run the following

`/etc/init.d/libvirtd restart`

`virsh shutdown <osname>`

`virsh start <osname>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPICE with VERDE: http://www.vbridges.com